# Trying to figure out a way to match items in two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am testing this code.

```
# Define the ticker list
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
tickers_list = ['AAPL', 'WMT', 'IBM', 'MU', 'BA', 'AXP']

# Fetch the data
import yfinance as yf
company_names = []
for item in tickers_list:
    my_stock = yf.Ticker(item)
    company_name = my_stock.info['longName']
    company_names.append(item + '-' + company_name)
df_names = DataFrame(company_names)
print(df_names)

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)             
data_hist = yf.download(tickers_list,'2020-05-15')['Adj Close']
print(data_hist.head(5))
```

The first DF looks like this.

```
                                                 0
0                                  AAPL-Apple Inc.
1                                 WMT-Walmart Inc.
2  IBM-International Business Machines Corporation
3                       MU-Micron Technology, Inc.
4                            BA-The Boeing Company
5                     AXP-American Express Company
```

The second DF looks like this.

```
            AAPL        AXP         BA          IBM         MU          WMT
Date                        
5/15/2020   307.709991  82.220001   120         116.980003  44.41       125.940002
5/18/2020   314.959991  88.410004   135.440002  121.559998  45.919998   127.660004
5/19/2020   313.140015  87.260002   130.440002  120.290001  45.119999   124.949997
5/20/2020   319.230011  90.730003   133.320007  121.379997  46.639999   125.449997
5/21/2020   316.850006  89.830002   139         119.120003  45.220001   124.989998
```

I want to combine these dataframes so the final result looks like this.

```
            Apple Inc.  American Express Company    The Boeing Company     International Business Machines Corporation     Micron Technology, Inc.    Walmart Inc.
            AAPL        AXP                         BA                     IBM                                             MU                         WMT
Date                        
5/15/2020   307.709991  82.220001                   120                    116.980003                                      44.41                      125.940002
5/18/2020   314.959991  88.410004                   135.440002             121.559998                                      45.919998                  127.660004
5/19/2020   313.140015  87.260002                   130.440002             120.290001                                      45.119999                  124.949997
5/20/2020   319.230011  90.730003                   133.320007             121.379997                                      46.639999                  125.449997
5/21/2020   316.850006  89.830002                   139                    119.120003                                      45.220001                  124.989998
```

I think it's going to require some kind of find because I can't match these tickers based on the ordinal position, because the `'yf.download'` seems to alpha-order the names of the fields as it runs.  I tried `concat` and `merge`.  Neither worked.  Any idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a dataframe, you can use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
for item in tickers_list:
    my_stock = yf.Ticker(item)
    company_name = my_stock.info['longName']
    d[item] = company_name
print(d)

{'AAPL': 'Apple Inc.',
 'WMT': 'Walmart Inc.',
 'IBM': 'International Business Machines Corporation',
 'MU': 'Micron Technology, Inc.',
 'BA': 'The Boeing Company',
 'AXP': 'American Express Company'}
```

And then you update the columns in the second dataframe with `map`:

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.map(d)+" - "+df2.columns
```

Output:

```
           Apple Inc. - AAPL  American Express Company - AXP  The Boeing Company - BA  International Business Machines Corporation - IBM  Micron Technology, Inc. - MU  Walmart Inc. - WMT
Date                                                                                                                                                                                      
5/15/2020         307.709991                       82.220001               120.000000                                         116.980003                     44.410000          125.940002
5/18/2020         314.959991                       88.410004               135.440002                                         121.559998                     45.919998          127.660004
5/19/2020         313.140015                       87.260002               130.440002                                         120.290001                     45.119999          124.949997
5/20/2020         319.230011                       90.730003               133.320007                                         121.379997                     46.639999          125.449997
5/21/2020         316.850006                       89.830002               139.000000                                         119.120003                     45.220001          124.989998
```

Comment: Wow!  This is a very cool trick David!  I never even knew you could do that!  Thanks for teaching me something new!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a dictionary `{ticker : ticker+name}` and than convert the column names:

```
d={'AAPL':'Apple Inc. AAPL'} #etc, simply split df1.str values by "-" to create this dict
df2.columns = [d.get(c) for c in df2.columns]
```